# Determine whether a file is a valid image format

Tags: c#, image

I am working for a small project in windows using C# where I need to determine whether a file (without any extension) is a valid image file or not. Is there any inbuilt library function so that I can simplify the task of doing it?

Comment: Which image format(s)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
Image.FromFile(path);
```

It throws if the file of `path` is not a valid image.