# How to check if the uploaded image file is fake using ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using FileUpload control on my ASP.NET C# application, for purpose of uploading images file and I want to check if the uploaded image is broken or not.

My application checks the extensions and it works fine, but if I uploads fake image file (such as txt file saved as image file) the server accept it.
 My question in short is How to prevent that?

Comment: Define "broken"... Also, what have you tried?

Comment: @Isma fake image such as txt file saved as image or image not displaying.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328713/determine-whether-a-file-is-a-valid-image-format or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670546/determine-if-file-is-an-image#670549

Comment: @Isma I will check the links, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Isma commented, define "broken".

But you can try to create a new System.Drawing.Image with it. If you want to validate anything else about it, then access it's properties. For instance you can check that the image is larger than 1 pixel if that suits your purpose. If an exception is thrown creating, or during your other checks, then it is (unlikely) a valid image.

```
    private static bool CheckImage(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var image = Image.FromFile(filename))
            {
                if(image.Height<2 && image.Width<2)
                    return false
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // probably should log more information here
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: that's works brother, thank you

Comment: private bool GetImageSize(Stream file)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(file);
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
This another answer worked for me